# how to get the position of the face in the esp32 cam example code?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

there is an example code for an esp32 cam called CameraWebServer and in it you can stream the video output of the esp32 cam and there is an option to turn on facial recognition so I am asking how can i access the cordinations of the face that the esp32 cam is detecting.

I tried to look for an answer in google and using chatGPT but I found nothing that works

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact problem as I'm building a face tracking system using the ESP32-Cam and managed to figure out how to get the position of the face without using the webserver, however I'm not sure how to use the information as anytime that I run a servo with the ESP32-Cam it reset itself as the camera function and the servo function interfere with each other.
I first used an old Face tracking code from https://robotzero.one/face-tracking-esp32-cam/
To make it run you need to first install ESP32 library version 1.0.4 as the new versions don't work.
I then stripped off all the WiFi and webserver part of the code and now anytime I run it I can get the screen position of the face on a 320x240 image size on my serial port without connecting it as a webserver.
the next stage is to slave an Arduino nano and get the data out using the I2C interface which I'm working on.

This is the current code that reads the face position data on serial port, hope this helps. in addition to this code you also need to download the
camera_index.h and camera_pins.h from the link above and place them in the same directory.

```
// MoveHead_ESP_V1_5
// Board AI Thinker ESP-CAM
// This module requires ESP32 ver 1.0.4 to run
// This works identifying the face position without the need of server


#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include "camera_index.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "fb_gfx.h"
#include "fd_forward.h"
 

#include <Wire.h>

 // ESP32-CAM doesn't have dedicated i2c pins, so we define our own. Let's choose 15 and 14
#define I2C_SDA 15
#define I2C_SCL 14
TwoWire I2Cbus = TwoWire(0);

int NewPositionX=0;
int NewPositionY=0;

int ScreenPosX = 0;
int ScreenPosY=0;

int ScreenSizeX = 320;
int ScreenSizeY=240;

int MinPan = 30;
int MaxPan = 150;
int MinTilt = 0;
int MaxTilt = 55;

 
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#include "camera_pins.h"
 
 
static inline mtmn_config_t app_mtmn_config()
{
  mtmn_config_t mtmn_config = {0};
  mtmn_config.type = FAST;
  mtmn_config.min_face = 80;
  mtmn_config.pyramid = 0.707;
  mtmn_config.pyramid_times = 4;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.score = 0.6;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.candidate_number = 20;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.score = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.candidate_number = 10;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.score = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.candidate_number = 1;
  return mtmn_config;
}
mtmn_config_t mtmn_config = app_mtmn_config();
 
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Loadong...");
  Serial.println();
 

  // Initialize I2C with our defined pins
  I2Cbus.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL, 100000);

  
 
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if (psramFound()) {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif
  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
 
  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);
 
 }
 
 

static void draw_face_boxes(dl_matrix3du_t *image_matrix, box_array_t *boxes)
{
  int x, y, w, h, i, half_width, half_height;
  fb_data_t fb;
  fb.width = image_matrix->w;
  fb.height = image_matrix->h;
  fb.data = image_matrix->item;
  fb.bytes_per_pixel = 3;
  fb.format = FB_BGR888;
  for (i = 0; i < boxes->len; i++) {
 
    // Convoluted way of finding face centre...
    x = ((int)boxes->box[i].box_p[0]);
    w = (int)boxes->box[i].box_p[2] - x + 1;
    half_width = w / 2;
    int face_center_pan = x + half_width; // image frame face centre x co-ordinate
 
    y = (int)boxes->box[i].box_p[1];
    h = (int)boxes->box[i].box_p[3] - y + 1;
    half_height = h / 2;
    int face_center_tilt = y + half_height;  // image frame face centre y co-ordinate
 
    //    assume QVGA 320x240
    //    int sensor_width = 320;
    //    int sensor_height = 240;
    //    int lens_fov = 45
  
    Serial.print("Face:");
    Serial.print(face_center_pan); 
    Serial.print(" X ");
    Serial.print(face_center_tilt);

// Map the screen positions to Servo positions
NewPositionX = map(face_center_pan, 0, ScreenSizeX, MinPan, MaxPan);
NewPositionY = map(face_center_tilt, 0, ScreenSizeY, MinTilt, MaxTilt);

// Display X,Y screen coordinate, speed, Pan and Tilt


    Serial.print("   Pan:");
    Serial.print(NewPositionX); 
    Serial.print(" Tilt:");
    Serial.println(NewPositionY);

// this doesn't work, it seems that the servo interfere with the camera
// this is the place to use I2C to send the pan and tilt position to Arduino via I2C




  }
}
 

void loop()
{

 // auto client = socket_server.accept();
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  dl_matrix3du_t *image_matrix = NULL;
 
  while (true) {
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    image_matrix = dl_matrix3du_alloc(1, fb->width, fb->height, 3);
 
    fmt2rgb888(fb->buf, fb->len, fb->format, image_matrix->item);
 
    box_array_t *net_boxes = NULL;
    net_boxes = face_detect(image_matrix, &mtmn_config);
 
    if (net_boxes) {
      draw_face_boxes(image_matrix, net_boxes);
      free(net_boxes->score);
      free(net_boxes->box);
      free(net_boxes->landmark);
      free(net_boxes);
    }
 
  
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    fb = NULL;
    dl_matrix3du_free(image_matrix);
  }
  
}
```